# Run a 16bits application on Windows 64bits

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, 16-bit

I need run a 16bits application on a windows 64bits without virtualization or XP mode.
Do you have a solution ?
My application have an user interface and she need to print and to access the disk.
It's a old monster, we don't have the source code (Delphi) and it's very specific (made on demand).
I think about a sort of encapsulation or a "translator" between the OS and the binary.
An idea ?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question at all, and doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. It's more applicable to be asked on Super User, which I myself have asked basically the same question: http://superuser.com/questions/662457/how-to-make-an-extremely-old-app-run-on-64bit-windows

Comment: good explanation here: http://superuser.com/questions/140953/why-cant-a-64-bit-os-run-a-16-bit-application

Comment: @WarrenP:  No, that's not a duplicate.  That link answers why it *isn't* possible, but this question is asking for a workaround - likely because they're running into the wall that is "it's impossible".

Comment: Yeah, the OP basically wants to change reality.  Whatever he thinks a "translator" is, that could be "not a virtual machine", is what we old time hackers call PEBKAC.  Problem exists between Keyboard and Chair.

Comment: I'd ask the question, why can't you use Virtualization (or an Emulator)?

Answer (score 4):

> I need run a 16 bit application on a Windows 64 bit system without virtualization.

That is not possible. The only way to run this application on such a system is via a virtualized environment of one form or another.

You wonder about some form of translator or adapter, but that is of course exactly what virtualization is. A 64 bit system cannot run a 16 bit process natively, ergo you need a virtualized environment in order to run it.